# PF('').show(); function does not work

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to pop up dialog window in Netbeans 8.0.2 Primefaces as shown http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/basic.xhtml

I  added primefaces-5.3.jar at my project but when I type PF for example:

```
<p:commandButton value="Show" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();" type="button" />               


<p:dialog header="Header" widgetVar="dlg1">
<h:outputText value="What we do in life, echoes in eternity!" />
```

Nothing happens and it shows me some error saying :The global variable "PF" is not declared.

Please, help me someone.

Comment: "*The global variable "PF" is not declared*" is unrelated as it is merely an IDE's warning that can safely be ignored. Press F12 to watch JavaScript errors, if any on the browser's console.

Comment: So do you see the error in the IDE or in the browser? Do you have `h:head` in your xhtml? Make sure you don't have an older PrimeFaces jar in your project as well.

Comment: Thank  you  a lot  for such a useful advice. I pressed F12 and found out that It was caused by script tag I added in head section :  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>     . I am a begginer programmer and just copied an  wrong example of jquery .  Now I can see the dialog window,  but the warrning still stays on. I will simply ignore this

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. It was caused by tag I wrongly added src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">

Now I can see dialog window , but the warning still stays on. I will ignore it...

Thanks all of you

Answer (score -3):

Change your code like this

```
<p:commandButton value="Show" onclick="dlg1.show();" type="button" />
```

And put this fragment in a form

```
<h:form>        
    <p:commandButton value="Show" onclick="dlg1.show();" type="button" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: `dlg1.show();` is only supported before PrimeFaces 4.0.

Comment: Watch your console in the browser, to look and error javascript or it might not well referenced library PrimeFaces